# How to force SET IDENTITY INSERT ON?

Tags: sql, sql-server, jtds

I am trying to copy a SQL Server database (including the IDs). I need identity insert to be on for every table. The problem I am running into is the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[abc] OFF;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[def] ON ; <---- Fails
```

I get this error:

> IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'master.dbo.abc'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'dbo.def'.

According to documentation:

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON.

which is why I assume this problem is because turning the identity insert off lags behind.

I am using Sqldeveloper with jtds 1.2.8 drivers.

Is it possible to force set identity on so that it turns off in the previous table? Is there a SQL syntax which can do both of the above at once? Could the problem be caused by the driver?

Comment: If I set `IDENTITY_INSERT` off in the same batch, I have no problems: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5b9680dc609b2eef817fad4601c13447). Perhaps `IDENTITY_INSERT` isn't `ON` on the table you think it is.

Comment: Are you runnig these two statements in the same batch? Side note: Is there any reason you are not just using backup and restore?

Comment: I think perhaps you have done something you were not expecting. Notice your message references the master database. I suspect you accidentally are using the master database for at least a portion of whatever you are running.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes it's the same batch. I ommited most of the statements since there is 17k  of them. They are automatically generated by Microsoft Server Management Studio.

Comment: I ran the same sql batch using plain java instead of using sqldeveloper and I didn't run into the problem.